# Registering client script blocks with script manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to update one of the sections on the aspx page by clicking on a button and I would like this to be done without any postbacks.

I have a ScriptManager placed inside the master page like so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
```

and I am trying to register a JavaScript into a Literal control on button click using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock. Below is what I have on the aspx page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel_Map" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock_Map" runat="server">
                <div id="mapArea" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px"></div>
                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
            </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadButton1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" OnClick="RadButton_Search_Click" Text="Search" OnClientClicking="validateSearchFilter"></telerik:RadButton>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void RadButton_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Testing();
}

Protected void Testing() 
{
    Literal1.Text = @"
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var user = 'http://www.robotwoods.com/dev/misc/bluecircle.png';

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(" + userLongitude + ", " + userLatitude + "), " + @"
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapArea'), mapOptions);

            var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(" + userLongitude + ", " + userLatitude + "), " + @" 
                map: myMap,
                icon: user
            });" + markers + @"} " + "\n window.onload = initialize; " + @"
    </script>";

    // Make Panel_Map visible
    Panel_Map.Visible = true;
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "testing", Literal1.Text, true);
}
```

I have tried using ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock as well but that didn't work. I have also tried alerting a random text in place of the 'Literal1.Text' but that doesn't seem to work either. I have tested the above JavaScript code and that worked without any issues but when I wrap it inside the UpdatePanel, it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The last boolean parameter of `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is used to automatically add the `<script>` tag for you, but in this case you have already add the tag inside your script string, then you have to set last parameter as `false` or remove the script tag from your string.

Comment: Hi Gidanmx2, thanks for your comment. I've tried removing the script tag and have set the last parameter to true but it still doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried doing the vice-versa (keeping the script tag, set the last parameter to false) but that doesn't seem to work as well. I will continue investigating what the issue is :)